# Merge XML files using XmlReader and XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml, merge

I am trying to merge multiple XML files in into one using `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` though my final file only contains the data from the last file.

I am using `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` because the XML files to merge are large in size.

What am I doing wrong in the code below?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string folder = @"C:\Temp\";
            string output = folder + "_all.xml";
            Encoding readEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

            XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            writerSettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            writerSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(new StreamWriter(output, false), writerSettings);
            bool firstFile = true;

            foreach (FileInfo file in new DirectoryInfo(folder).GetFiles("*.xml").Where(f => f.Name != "_all.xml"))
            {
                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(file.FullName, readEncoding));
                while(reader.Read())
                {

                    switch (reader.NodeType)
                    {
                        case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            if (firstFile && reader.Name == "CYPHS:CYPHS")
                            {
                                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI);
                                writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                            }
                            else if (firstFile && reader.Name == "CYP000")
                                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                            else if (firstFile && reader.Name.StartsWith("C000"))
                                writer.WriteNode(reader, false);
                            else if (!firstFile && reader.Name != "CYPHS:CYPHS" && reader.Name != "CYP000" && !reader.Name.StartsWith("C000"))
                                writer.WriteNode(reader, false);
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                firstFile = false;
                reader.Close();
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

File 1

```
<CYPHS:CYPHS xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CYPHS-v1-5 CYPHSCYPHS_XMLSchema-v1-5.xsd"
xmlns:CYPHS="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CYPHS-v1-5"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CYP000>
    <C000010>File 1</C000010>
    <CYP001>
      <C001901>File 1</C001901>
      <CYP101>
        <C101902>File 1</C101902>
        <CYP102>
          <C102902>File 1</C102902>
        </CYP102>
      </CYP101>
      <CYP002>
        <C002901>File 1</C002901>
      </CYP002>
    </CYP001>
  </CYP000>
</CYPHS:CYPHS>
```

File 2

```
<CYPHS:CYPHS xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CYPHS-v1-5 CYPHSCYPHS_XMLSchema-v1-5.xsd"
xmlns:CYPHS="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CYPHS-v1-5"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CYP000>
    <C000010>File 2</C000010>
    <CYP001>
      <C001901>File 2</C001901>
      <CYP101>
        <C101902>File 2</C101902>
        <CYP102>
          <C102902>File 2</C102902>
        </CYP102>
      </CYP101>
      <CYP002>
        <C002901>File 2</C002901>
      </CYP002>
    </CYP001>
  </CYP000>
</CYPHS:CYPHS>
```

Should be merged into file as so:

```
<CYPHS:CYPHS xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CYPHS-v1-5 CYPHSCYPHS_XMLSchema-v1-5.xsd"
xmlns:CYPHS="http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CYPHS-v1-5"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CYP000>
    <C000010>File 1</C000010>
    <CYP001>
      <C001901>File 1</C001901>
      <CYP101>
        <C101902>File 1</C101902>
        <CYP102>
          <C102902>File 1</C102902>
        </CYP102>
      </CYP101>
      <CYP002>
        <C002901>File 1</C002901>
      </CYP002>
    </CYP001>
    <CYP001>
      <C001901>File 2</C001901>
      <CYP101>
        <C101902>File 2</C101902>
        <CYP102>
          <C102902>File 2</C102902>
        </CYP102>
      </CYP101>
      <CYP002>
        <C002901>File 2</C002901>
      </CYP002>
    </CYP001>
  </CYP000>
</CYPHS:CYPHS>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure where you went wrong, but it seems most straightforward to check the [`Depth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.depth(v=vs.110).aspx), [`LocalName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.localname(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`NamespaceURI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.namespaceuri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties of [`XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when combining your XML files.  I strongly recommend *against* hardcoding the namespace *prefixes* since the prefix can be replaced with any other prefix without changing the semantics of the XML file.

One thing to note: [`XmlWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader, bool)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wd6aw1b(v=vs.110).aspx) advances the reader to the beginning of the next node, so if you subsequently call `Read()` **and there is no whitespace in the file** you'll skip over the next element.  With this in mind, when working directly with `XmlReader`, it's better to test both with and without spacing.

Thus:

```
public class XmlConcatenate
{
    public static void ConcatenateAllFiles()
    {
        string folder = "C:\\Temp\\";
        string output = folder + "_all.xml";
        Encoding readEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default; // WHY NOT Encoding.UTF8 !?

        var files = new DirectoryInfo(folder).GetFiles("*.xml").Where(f => f.Name != "_all.xml").Select(f => f.FullName).Select(n => (TextReader)new StreamReader(n, readEncoding));

        using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(output, false))
        {
            Concatenate(files, textWriter);
        }
    }

    public static void Concatenate(IEnumerable<TextReader> inputs, TextWriter output)
    {
        var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment };
        var whiteSpace = new StringBuilder();
        int indent = 0;

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, writerSettings))
        {
            var writeDepth = 0;
            var first = true;

            foreach (var input in inputs)
            {
                using (input)
                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(input))
                {
                    bool alreadyRead = false;
                    while (!reader.EOF && (alreadyRead || reader.Read()))
                    {
                        alreadyRead = false;
                        switch (reader.NodeType)
                        {
                            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                                {
                                    if (reader.Depth == 0 && reader.LocalName == "CYPHS" && reader.NamespaceURI == "http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CYPHS-v1-5")
                                    {
                                        if (writeDepth == 0)
                                        {
                                            writer.WriteWhitespace(whiteSpace.ToString());
                                            writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI);
                                            writer.WriteAttributes(reader, true);
                                            writeDepth++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if (reader.Depth == 1 && reader.LocalName == "CYP000" && reader.NamespaceURI == "")
                                    {
                                        if (writeDepth == 1)
                                        {
                                            indent = whiteSpace.ToString().Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Length;

                                            writer.WriteWhitespace(whiteSpace.ToString());
                                            writer.WriteStartElement(reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI);
                                            writeDepth++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if (reader.Depth == 2)
                                    {
                                        if (reader.LocalName.StartsWith("C000") && reader.NamespaceURI == "")
                                        {
                                            if (first)
                                            {
                                                first = false;
                                                writer.WriteWhitespace(whiteSpace.ToString());
                                                writer.WriteNode(reader, false);
                                                alreadyRead = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            writer.WriteWhitespace(whiteSpace.ToString());
                                            writer.WriteNode(reader, false);
                                            alreadyRead = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    whiteSpace.Length = 0; // Clear accumulated whitespace.
                                }
                                break;
                            case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
                                {
                                    whiteSpace.Append(reader.Value);
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            while (writeDepth-- > 0)
            {
                if (indent > 0)
                    writer.WriteWhitespace("\n" + new string(' ', indent * writeDepth));
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bit of a nuisance getting the spacing to merge, if you don't care about preserving the spacing you can simplify the code substantially.

Working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PsC7lu).

You might not want to use [`System.Text.Encoding.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reading your XML files.  From the docs:

> Because all Default encodings lose data, you might use UTF8 instead. UTF-8 is often identical in the U+00 to U+7F range, but can encode other characters without loss.

Answer (score 1):

Like This

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication53
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file1 =
                "<CYPHS:CYPHS xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CYPHS-v1-5 CYPHSCYPHS_XMLSchema-v1-5.xsd\"" +
                    " xmlns:CYPHS=\"http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CYPHS-v1-5\"" +
                    " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
                      "<CYP000>" +
                        "<C000010>File 1</C000010>" +
                        "<CYP001>" +
                          "<C001901>File 1</C001901>" +
                          "<CYP101>" +
                            "<C101902>File 1</C101902>" +
                            "<CYP102>" +
                              "<C102902>File 1</C102902>" +
                            "</CYP102>" +
                          "</CYP101>" +
                          "<CYP002>" +
                            "<C002901>File 1</C002901>" +
                          "</CYP002>" +
                        "</CYP001>" +
                      "</CYP000>" +
                    "</CYPHS:CYPHS>";
            XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Parse(file1);

            XElement doc1_CYP000 = doc1.Descendants("CYP000").FirstOrDefault();

            string file2 =
                "<CYPHS:CYPHS xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CYPHS-v1-5 CYPHSCYPHS_XMLSchema-v1-5.xsd\"" +
                " xmlns:CYPHS=\"http://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/messages/CYPHS-v1-5\"" +
                " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
                  "<CYP000>" +
                    "<C000010>File 2</C000010>" +
                    "<CYP001>" +
                      "<C001901>File 2</C001901>" +
                      "<CYP101>" +
                        "<C101902>File 2</C101902>" +
                        "<CYP102>" +
                          "<C102902>File 2</C102902>" +
                        "</CYP102>" +
                      "</CYP101>" +
                      "<CYP002>" +
                        "<C002901>File 2</C002901>" +
                      "</CYP002>" +
                    "</CYP001>" +
                  "</CYP000>" +
                "</CYPHS:CYPHS>";

            XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Parse(file2);

            XElement doc2_CYP000 = doc2.Descendants("CYP000").FirstOrDefault();
            doc1_CYP000.Add(doc2_CYP000.Descendants());

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different solution could be to use a custom `XmlReader`-implementation to concat the files while reading them.
Then use this custom reader along with an `XmlWriter` to create the merged file.

The custom `XmlReader` keeps internal `XmlReader`s for each file.
The intro/end is only read from the first file.
Only the relevant (to-be-appended) elements are read from the other files.

1. create an `XmlReader` for the first file
2. read up to the point where elements should be appended
3. for each subsequent file

   1. create a new `XmlReader`
   2. skip ahead to the first relevant element
   3. read the relevant elements
   4. dispose the reader
4. read the rest of the first file (resume the reader from step 1)
5. dispose the reader

**Example implementation**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

public static class XmlConcatenator
{
    // first: pause reading at the end of this element, will resume after subsequent streams are read
    // subsequent: stop reading at the end of this element
    private const string StopAtEndOf = "CYP000";

    // first: (ignores this)
    // subsequent: skip ahead to the first instance of this element
    private const string ResumeAtFirst = "CYP001";

    private static readonly XmlReaderSettings XmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings() { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore };
    private static readonly XmlWriterSettings XmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, Indent = true };

    public static void Concat(Stream outStream, Stream[] fileStreams)
    {
        using var reader = XmlConcatReader.Create(fileStreams);
        using var writer = XmlWriter.Create(outStream, XmlWriterSettings);
        writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
    }

    private class XmlConcatReader : XmlReader
    {
        private readonly XmlReader _firstReader;
        private readonly IEnumerator<Stream> _streams;
        private XmlReader _currentReader;

        private XmlConcatReader(Stream first, IEnumerable<Stream> streams)
        {
            _firstReader = XmlReader.Create(first, XmlReaderSettings);
            _streams = streams.GetEnumerator();
            _currentReader = _firstReader;
        }

        public static XmlReader Create(Stream[] inputStreams)
        {
            if (!(inputStreams?.Length > 1))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(inputStreams)} must contain at least two streams");
            }

            return new XmlConcatReader(inputStreams[0], inputStreams.Skip(1));
        }

        public override bool Read()
        {
            var b = _currentReader.Read();
            if (_currentReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && _currentReader.LocalName == StopAtEndOf)
            {
                // note: _firstReader is disposed at the end. See: Dispose(bool)
                if (!ReferenceEquals(_currentReader, _firstReader))
                {
                    _currentReader.Dispose();
                }

                if (_streams.MoveNext())
                {
                    _currentReader = XmlReader.Create(_streams.Current, XmlReaderSettings);

                    while (_currentReader.Read())
                    {
                        if (_currentReader.LocalName == ResumeAtFirst)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _currentReader = _firstReader;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return b;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _firstReader?.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        public override XmlNodeType NodeType => _currentReader.NodeType;
        public override string LocalName => _currentReader.LocalName;
        public override string NamespaceURI => _currentReader.NamespaceURI;
        public override string Prefix => _currentReader.Prefix;
        public override string Value => _currentReader.Value;
        public override int Depth => _currentReader.Depth;
        public override string BaseURI => _currentReader.BaseURI;
        public override bool IsEmptyElement => _currentReader.IsEmptyElement;
        public override int AttributeCount => _currentReader.AttributeCount;
        public override bool EOF => _currentReader.EOF;
        public override ReadState ReadState => _currentReader.ReadState;
        public override XmlNameTable NameTable => _currentReader.NameTable;
        public override string GetAttribute(string name) => _currentReader.GetAttribute(name);
        public override string GetAttribute(string name, string namespaceURI) => _currentReader.GetAttribute(name, namespaceURI);
        public override string GetAttribute(int i) => _currentReader.GetAttribute(i);
        public override string LookupNamespace(string prefix) => _currentReader.LookupNamespace(prefix);
        public override bool MoveToAttribute(string name) => _currentReader.MoveToAttribute(name);
        public override bool MoveToAttribute(string name, string ns) => _currentReader.MoveToAttribute(name, ns);
        public override bool MoveToElement() => _currentReader.MoveToElement();
        public override bool MoveToFirstAttribute() => _currentReader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
        public override bool MoveToNextAttribute() => _currentReader.MoveToNextAttribute();
        public override bool ReadAttributeValue() => _currentReader.ReadAttributeValue();
        public override void ResolveEntity() => _currentReader.ResolveEntity();
    }
}
```

**Example of use**

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var input = new[] { "in1.xml", "in2.xml" };
        var output = "output.xml";

        var inputStreams = input.Select(p => File.Open(p, FileMode.Open)).ToArray();
        using var outputStream = File.Create(output);

        XmlConcatenator.Concat(outputStream, inputStreams);

        foreach (var stream in inputStreams)
        {
            stream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```